# How to create an instance of a class from an instance of that class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I would like to have a class with a method that creates a new instance of its superclass (a.k.a. "parent" class).

In addition, I would like to subclass the class described above, and have this subclass inherit the method and then be able to use that method to create more instances of its own subclass.

But, when I try to do it like this...

```
class Superclass:
    def makeNew(self):
        return self.__class__() #this isn't making a clean copy

class Subclass(Superclass):
    def __init__(self, value = [1]):
        self.value = value

    def setValue(self, newValue):
        self.value[0] = newValue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Subclass()
    s.setValue(5)
    other = s.makeNew()
    print(s.value)
    print(other.value)
```

I get

```
>>> [5] #s.value
>>> [5] #other.value
```

Why doesn't `self.__class__()` give me a clean copy of the superclass?

What am I doing wrong? How can I create the class I want to?

Comment: What do you consider a "clean copy"? What are you getting instead? Regardless, one other way of doing it would be to define a `@staticmethod` in the subclass that will create and return new instances. You can call it with `s.make_new_instance()` if `s` is an instance of the subclass (and that's the name you gave the staticmethod).

Comment: By "clean copy" I mean that it's completely separate from the original `s`. It should print `[5]\n[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a problem with your `makeNew` method; that's a problem with your `__init__`.  When you have a mutable default argument, modifying that value will modify all your future defaults.  What you should do instead is this:

```
def __init__(self, value=None):
    if value is None:
        value = [1]
    # ...
```

That way, every new instance is creating a new list instead of just more references to the same list.

On a side note, it doesn't look like you need `value` to be a list.  Of course, other code that you don't show here may require it, but if this is all the code, all you need is `self.value = ...`.  Since you are now reassigning `self.value` instead of modifying it, you can use the default argument just fine.

Comment: Nice catch! Lists & dicts are almost always a bad idea for default arguments. The none solution is my fav, but if it doesn't really need to have a default argument one could simple leave it out altogether.

Comment: The problem _is_ with the `makeNew` base class method. When it calls `self.__class__()` it's referencing the subclass if it's called with its `self` argument set to a subclass instance (as would be the case with `s.makeNew()` as shown in the question).

Comment: @martineau: I'm not sure why that's a problem.  It would be rather strange if calling `makeNew` on a subclass gave you an instance of the super class, so I would call that expected behavior, not a problem.

Comment: That's not what I said. The question is "Why doesn't `self.__class__()` give me a clean copy of the ***superclass***? (emphasis mine)—I was just explaining why.